# Доступ к локальным переменным

Tags: переменные, java

Можно ли получить доступ к локальным переменным из `main`, объявленным внутри `public` метода того же класса, в котором объявлен `main` и например изменить их значение?

Comment: А разве они существуют когда-либо кроме выполнения данного метода? Что Вы собираетесь менять?

Comment: если какому  то методу нужно поменять локальную переменную в методе main, то пусть возвращает его как значение, а main сам разберется, как менять.

Comment: Необходимо синхронизировать доступ к переменным объявленным в классе, но чтобы именно в классе, а не в методе.

Comment: упорядочите свои мысли. смысл Вашей фразы уплывает.

Comment: @alexlz: Я не уверен, что это стандартная терминология. Имеется в виду отличие _ссылки_ на объект (то есть, значения переменной) от значений _внутри_ самого объекта (его полей, элементов массива и т. п.). Для языка с иммутабельными объектами различия не было бы.

Comment: @VladD вроде понял. Вариация вопроса "а как это будет по-русски".

Answer (score 4):

Нет. Видимость таких переменных ограничена границами метода. Они существуют только во время выполнения метода. Но есть исключение, когда видимость может быть расширена через замыкание, хотя непосредственно значение пременной изменить будет нельзя, но можно будет изменить состояние.

Comment: Вы по сути правы, но для обоснования одной лишь видимости недостаточно. Пример: https://ideone.com/TNOP6B или там https://ideone.com/mywPWU

Comment: @VladD, отличные примеры.

Comment: @avp: спасибо!

Comment: @VladD Отчасти согласен с вами. Но есть пара нюансов касательно ваших примеров:

1. Изменяется не значение переменной, а состояние.
2. Переменные объявлены не в public методах того же класса, а в самом main, и доступ к ним производится вообще говоря из других классов.

Хотя если смотреть на комментарий автора к своему же вопросу, то я вообще перестаю понимать суть вопроса.

Comment: @a_gura: Вы правы. Но состояние — то есть, видимость элементов массива в нашем случае — _также_ ограничено границами метода. Тем не менее, внешний метод может их изменить. Таким образом, одной только области видимости недостаточно. Надо ещё упомянуть, что (1) сами переменные передаются как параметр лишь по значению, (2) замыкание в Java может быть проведено лишь по `final`-переменным.

Comment: @VladD Нет, видимость в данном случае уже не ограничена методом. В этом вся суть замыкания. Вы же можете вернуть из метода инстанс вашего анонимного класса, который ссылается на замкнутый контекст с переменной и обеспечить доступ к ней через геттеры всем клиентам этого метода.

Comment: @a_gura: И снова вы правы. Но тогда локальные переменные из `main` не обязательно имеют локальную видимость.

Comment: @VladD Совместно установили истину :) Дополню ответ.

Comment: @VladD а нельзя на пальцах, чем значение отличается от состояния (я-то считал, что значение переменной -- часть состояния). И как замыкание расширяет видимость?